# Avoid reading all data into memory from hdf5 file when performing operations

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'm new to the HDF5 format, and I'm using h5py for these operations. I'm wondering about what exactly happens when I have a very large data set and perform some kind of operation on it. For instance:

```
>>> f = h5py.File("mytestfile.hdf5", "w")
>>> dset = f.create_dataset("mydataset", (100000000,), dtype=np.float64)
>>> dset[...] = np.linspace(0, 100, 100000000)
>>> myResult = f["mydataset"][:] * 15
# Graph myResult, or something
```

Is the entirety of myResult in memory now? Was dset also in memory? Is there a way to only read from the disk into memory part by part, like 100,000 points at a time or so, to avoid overflow (let's assume I might end up with data even far larger than the example, say, 50GB worth)? Is there a way to do so efficiently, and in a modular fashion (such that simply saying `data * 100` automatically does the operation in chunks, and stores the results again in a new place)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the `h5py` docs discuss this sort of thing?  I vaguely recall reading about chunks and loading ranges.  I'd suggest starting with small files, learn to use those, and then build toward the large stuff.

Comment: As far as I recall, h5py by itself doesn't support out-of-core computation. You could loop over smaller slices of your dataset in Python, perform the computation, then write the results to another dataset. [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/expr_class.html?highlight=expression) and [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/examples/array-hdf5.html?highlight=hdf5) both support out-of-core operations on HDF5 arrays.

Comment: Would it be advisable to use the expression class in Pytables you linked to to this end? Or is there a more standard way of doing it? (Just feels weird passing a string). Thanks